# MySQL or Oracle Associate Certification?

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have 15+ years in software development and 7+ in web development, and I want to get a certification in another area, like DBA. I have 7+ years of experience like MySQL developer. Which is better for certification? MySQL or Oracle 11g? Which of the two is more hired and better paid?

Comment: One thing I've noted is that there are quite a few companies that have a mixture of database products. So it is probably a good idea to certify in one area, but familiarize yourself with another product too. I don't really feel qualified to give an answer to your question, but big corporations will tend to use Oracle and they are the ones with deep pockets.

Answer (score 3):

Forgive me for sounding a little biased, but I would recommend MySQL DBA Certification for you without hesitation. I say this without reservation because that is how I become a MySQL DBA.

[I actually wrote an earlier post about making such a transition from school, from a willing developer, from an unwilling developer, and from a sysadmin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2913/877).

I also wrote [another post on how DBAs should properly interact with developers and project managers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2485/877).

I would personally say MySQL positions are very underrated in the eyes of most companies, yet the demand is out there. I feel have been respected because of my certification (unique experience, result vary based on who hires). I certified back in August 2007 with my employer paying for the course. At that time, no instructor-led MySQL course was required for certification. Now that Oracle owns MySQL, that may have changed. Please check with Oracle on that.

Most companies that hire MySQL DBAs may expect you to know everything else, (Linux, Apache, Nagios, Munin, JBoss, PHP, Perl, Python, etc). Many other companies may use only MySQL. Overall, you have to be selective when looking. The more disciplines/skills you have outside of MySQL, the better your employment chances are.

What makes the most money is a different story. Hands down, Oracle DBA/Developers make more money. Certification is more expensive because Oracle Associate requires only an exam. To earn deeper Certifications in Oracle, you take necessary exam(s) and you must attend at least one instructor-led Oracle course (Exams run about $200-$300, while the courses run $3,000/each). While Oracle Certification is more rigorous, the respect you get for working with Oracle and the money will indeed come. You can pretty much write your own ticket an an OCP. Going for OCA is a good start.

Regardless of MySQL, Oracle or any other RDBMS, nothing can substitute for having working experience. Due diligence in all DBAs takes will train you to certify quickly.

If there are any Oracle gurus out there, please post your own answers on Oracle as I am sure there a lot more positive things that can be said for Oracle.