# How to better perform a query split into subqueries in PHP

Tags: mysql, php

In PHP I have made this query:

```
$getTrackID = $this->db->query("SELECT `id`,`uid` FROM `tracks`, `users` WHERE `time` > CURDATE() - interval 1 year AND `uid`=`idu` AND `public` > 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10");
$TrackID = $getTrackID->fetch_assoc();
$id=$TrackID['id'];
$xid=$TrackID['uid'];
```

The problem is that it takes 1 sec to return the result. I saw [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/77011/82129) question and it seems better practice split big queries into subqueries.

Is this the case? To better perform should I need to use something like:

```
$getTrackTime = $this->db->query("SELECT `id`,`uid` FROM `tracks`, `users` WHERE `time` > CURDATE() - interval 1 year AND `uid`=`idu`");
// Declare the rows array
$rows = array();
while($row = $getTrackTime->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Store the result into the array
    $rowsTime[] = $row;
}

$getTrackPublic = $this->db->query(sprintf("SELECT `%s`,`%s` FROM `tracks`, `users` WHERE `public` > 0",$rowsTime['id'],$rowsTime['uid']));
$rows = array();
while($row = $getTrackPublic->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rowsPublic[] = $row;
}
...
```

Comment: @Strawberry why it's not a dba question by the way? It's about MySQL

Comment: @Strawberry my question is about performance indeed (I saw many others here)...I edited the question since I forgot the relation between `tracks` and `users` tables. AND `uid`=`idu`

Comment: @Strawberry Yes,`tracks.id` and `users.idu`

Comment: A covering index on time and the other column would probably perform better

Comment: If you're using commas to join tables, you still have some walking to do ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry that wasn't my point...also I don't see how using join could be better for performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quickly get into the habit of writing your queries with some kind of formatting, proper joins, and with properly qualified column names. It makes it much easier to understand. E.g.:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.uid
  FROM tracks t
  JOIN users u
    ON u.idu = t.uid
 WHERE t.time > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
   AND u.public > 0 
 ORDER
    BY RAND() 
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but why it's wrong in my case something like this http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/77011/82129 ? Where he said "You might run these queries"

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say

Comment: I'm talking about this part: instead of this single query:

`SELECT * FROM tag
JOIN tag_post ON tag_post.tag_id = tag.id
JOIN post ON tag_post.post_id = post.id
WHERE tag.tag = 'mysql';`
You might run these queries:

`SELECT * FROM tag WHERE tag = 'mysql';
SELECT * FROM tag_post WHERE tag_id=1234;
SELECT * FROM post WHERE post.id IN (123,456,567,9098,8904);`

Comment: @SimonLeCat - `ORDER BY RAND()` is significant.  You left it out of that comment.  We need to know what the goal is.  Also, _please_ provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the relevant tables.  We _need_ to know the indexes, etc.

Comment: As for that link about changing to 3 queries... I know and respect Baron, Vadim, and Peter, but I disagree with this misleading suggestion.  Most of the arguments in favor of the split up are so rare as to be not worth mentioning.  Stick with a single query with `JOINs`, then let's work on improving it.

Comment: @RickJames Thanks Rick, I read here around that in terms of performance, using or not `JOIN` is exactly the same. Is that correct?