# Is it better to use C# for complex business logic that uses SQL and then run it from SQL Server or do everything from within SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-clr

I find a C-based language like C# to be better in terms of programming constructs for handling complex code. So has anyone here used SQL simply to extract data and managed their business logic in C++ or C#? How was your experience?

Is it better performance-wise to be doing this?

Comment: SQL is not a programming language - it is a query language.    Yes it is common to have a business layer in something like C#.

Comment: But where should you manage your business logic?  The most reasonable approach would be to let the database what it is good at, which can include some business logic, and then use your programming language to complete the process.  It is not an **either/or** decision.

Comment: I ask it because I have seen a lot of people, so many posting their questions here too, including myself, writing whatever possible in SQL with the help of IF statements and while loops and other constructs by SQL itself. It would make my job easier it seems if I did the business logic in the programming language and used SQL for largely querying and updating data.

Comment: Ravi I've closed this a duplicate, I hope you'll take the time to read the answers there, including [this one](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5927/1396).

Comment: Thank you Jack, that is what I was precisely looking for. I will read all answers there too. Thanks.